It‘s not possible to click on the search box using the select2 library
When I click on the search box, it doesn’t work. I can‘t type any characters into it. Can someone help me?
device: macbook air
browser: chrome
current_version select2 used:  4.0.7
enter image description here
enter image description here
I want to be able to input characters when clicking on the search box.

Does this answer your question? HTML combo box with option to type an entry
